# Rails guard live reload and assets digests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, guard, livereload

Rails 5.0.7 project, try to use Guard LiveReload

```
guard 'livereload', apply_css_live: true
```

When livereload fetch css assets its add timestamp to the end of the asset path **?livereload=1540612100363**

If

> config.assets.digest = true

then assets returns

```
No route matches [GET] "/assets/frontend-4b8741dedeaf0b52efed3e9e5b443b5203c14dea888d01ac03aad0c107d1d3e1.css"
```

If digest = false then assets works and livereload successfully fetch it.

How to make assets compilation with digest=true and with timestamp in the assets url?

Comment: What's the purpose of live reloading? Rails' default development config will serve assets dynamically anyway.

Comment: Timestamp adds automatically by livereload.

Comment: That doesn't explain why you need to use guard though. By default, you can just change a CSS file and reload in the browser.